# I understand P-value but I am not sure about this question

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, self-study, multiple-regression, p-value

What probability indicates the p-value? (more than one answer possible)

a: The probability of a type I error.

b: The probability of a type II error.

c: The probability of rejecting the alternative hypothesis when it is false.

d: The probability of rejecting the null hypothesis when it is false.

I think None of the following answers is correct. Can anyone answer this question and explain to me?

Comment: self-study? please add the tag if so.

Comment: Check other questions tagged `p-value`: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/p-value I am sure you'll find there multiple relevant answers. Also check the tour on how the site works: http://stats.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: I already put my effort on this question and understand that

Type I Error is defined as rejecting the null hypothesis when it is in fact true.

Type II error is defined as not rejecting the null hypothesis when it is false.

p-value is the region when I want to make a decision about rejecting null hypothesis.

However, I am not quite sure about this question, so I need help. Does anybody can help?

Comment: Well this is rather upsetting. How about "Between zero and four answers possible"? See [this paper](http://ftp.isds.duke.edu/WorkingPapers/03-26.pdf) distinguishing $\alpha$ from $p$

Comment: What do you mean by zero and four answers possible? Keine der folgenden Antworten ist richtig? @conjugateprior

Comment: Genau. None are correct. P is not a type 1 (or a type 2) error rate, although it seems that your textbook or instructor thinks it is.

Comment: Think of it this way: in the repeated trials to which any error rate can apply, the p value will be different in each trial. It's a random variable (because it's a function of random data)

Answer (score -1):

Strictly speaking, none of them, but the closest is [a], not [c].

You cannot do [c] based on p-value comparisons.  It is not an "error".  Rejecting the alternative when it is false means accepting the null when it is true.  Can't do that.

See the table at this wiki article on FDR:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_discovery_rate#Classification_of_m_hypothesis_tests

p-value is essentially V/m0.

Comment: Welcome to this site! Please, review our guidelines on how [homework questions are handled](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on this site.

Comment: @chl, not sure what you mean.  Fairly certain that this was a homework question can be rejected at p<<0.01.

Comment: None of them are correct? @Guest

Comment: @NongNick There are subtle differences between a p-value and the alpha-threshold that defines Type I error.  The former is where your observed statistic falls among all the possible values of the statistic generated when the null is true.  The latter is a threshold criterion you apply to test hypotheses.